# How to control what a user sees depending on company role, windowsform visual studio?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I have a login table and a employees table. The emplyee table specifies whether a person is a store manager or team leader. In the app, the team leader should only see employee information for his team but a store manager should see all store employees.

Would I need to link employees and login table somehow? I'm not sure how the logic side of it works so that in my code I can distinguish between the two when logged in.

Comment: Can you provide a sketch of your database layout?

Comment: @K.Madden : about your suggested edit and your answer, how did you figure out that OP is using SQLServer and vb.net ?

Comment: @Pac0 being honest i took a swing and a guess. Just trying to be helpful

Comment: @K.Madden Yes,, well that's fine if you want to answer, but editing the *question* to match a guess goes a bit too far, in my opinion (anyway, I see that the edit has already been rejected). As far as we know, until OP confirm the opposite, the question is not specific (which not a good thing for Stack Overflow standard, by the way)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to first create a login form which could just be a simple 2 textboxes (username,password) and a submit button.

Then when they type and then press a submit button have a sql command that searches the database first to see if they exist etc. then pull the info from the database stating weather or not they are a store manager or team leader.

Then you could use a 'sqldatareader' if you are using a sql server. Put what level the person logging in  is into a variable e.g

```
dim cmd as sqlcommand("select * from database where UserName = @username and Password = @password",con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernameTxtBox.text)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordTxtBox.text)

con.Open()
Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
 rdr.Read()
if rdr.hasrows() then
dim emplyee_level as string = rdr("NAME OF COLUMN WHERE EMPLOYEE LEVEL STORED")
end if
```

then have an if else statement kind of like

```
if emplyee_level = "Store Manager" then
Me.Hide()
ManagerForm.Show()
else if emplyee_level = "Team Leader" then
Me.Hide()
teamLeaderForm.Show()
end if
```

which depending on level will show corresponding form which will then have an if else statement kind of like provide only what is needed/accessible for it user.

Excuse any errors or spelling did this on the train. Best of luck!